# AS3: button doesn't work. Did I use the wrong function to exit the previous scene?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, flash

This is my function to go from scene 1 to scene 2.

bool 1&2 are `boolean` conditions that need to be true in order to move to the next scene.

It works for the most part, however when we reach scene 2, the "continue" button to move on to scene 3 no longer functions (but it works fine when tested without scene 1). Perhaps I should be using a different event?

```
function next (event:Event): void {
    if (bool1==true && bool2==true){
        gotoAndStop(1,"Scene 2");
    }
}
addEventListener (Event.EXIT_FRAME, next);
```

by the way the continue button on scene 2 is coded this way:

```
function clickContinue (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(1,"Scene 3");   
}   
contBTN.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, clickContinue);
```

Comment: what triggers the EXIT_FRAME event?  You may be stuck in a loop here.

Comment: in other words, if you aren't removing that listener, every time you try to exit a frame, it will check the bools and land back on scene 2, frame 1

Comment: Yes YES! Thank you so much. I added removeEventListener then it worked perfectly :)